# iOS8 : Saving array into user defaults makes app "pause"

Tags: arrays, ios8, nsuserdefaults, preferences

This bug is 1 hour old, from the recent iOS8 update. Basically, we're saving an array of dictionaries in the NSUserDefault Preferences and it was working fine before, and isn't now.

Symptoms : the app reads the line and just stops without crashing or any error. No message of any kind. Nothing logs even after several minutes.

No idea why or how, any suggestion is welcome.

If this is of any help, this is the line that crashes :

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:credentialsList forKey:CONFIG_Credentials];
```

This array contains one dictionary per user with all its credentials.

Comment: Any log messages related to your app from the device console?

Comment: No that's the thing. Everything inserts just fine in the user defaults, its just when i try to insert my Array (containing a dictionary). I literally have zero information about what/how this is happening...

Comment: wait, you said DEVICE console, i didn't check that one. I'll give it a look

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found a workaround with this issue.

I've read that the NSUSerDefaults where an issue to many people ( [here for example](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1018520#1018520) ) but in my case it was just this :

**Saving an NSMutableArray in the NSUserDefaults**

Now i noticed that saving arrays works just fine, its only the mutable ones that caused problems ( reason unkown, see comments above ). So i simply created an array and initiated it with the mutable one, and saved the array instead of the mutable one.

Like this :

```
//My mutable array is called credentialsList
NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:credentialsList];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:temp forKey:CONFIG_Credentials];
```